# Error on creating Pivot Table in Excel from .net web application

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, export-to-excel, pivot-table

In my web application, I am using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel to generate a pivot table in Excel. While Executing the application in my Visual studio IDE, the code is working fine and I am getting the Excel file. But when I hosted the same on IIS, my code is not working and I am receiving the following error

Message: Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManagerParserErrorException: The message received from the server could not be parsed. Common causes for this error are when the response is modified by calls to Response.Write(), response filters, HttpModules, or server trace is enabled.
Details: Error parsing near 'Retrieving the COM c'.

Please guide me to overcome this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Automation from a service (IIS is a service) poses several problems... but main point is - you should NOT use Office automation server-side as MS says here http://support.microsoft.com/default.aspx?scid=kb;EN-US;q257757#kb2

see also here [Problems with office automation in asp.net. I can use alternatives such as open-office, if I knew how](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2653740/problems-with-office-automation-in-asp-net-i-can-use-alternatives-such-as-open-o)

If you need to modify/create Excel files there are some libraries out there which work support your scenario (for example Aspose.Cells, Spreadsheetgear, Flexcel etc.)