# Word Mail merge in asp.net c# to add several pages and show

Tags: c#, asp.net, ms-word, mailmerge

I have created a word mail merge in asp.net C#. I need to replace MergeField with data from a datatable. The problem is, only the first page shows correctly, the other pages get added, but with no data as i would want to it.
I want to iterate to the end of datatable rows, generate a word doc for each row and have all these docs in one word file which will then be opened.
I have attached the entire code.

```
using Word = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word;

public void GenerateDoc(DataTable dt)
{
    string schoolName = "Name 1";
    string schoolAddress = "Address 1";
    //OBJECT OF MISSING "NULL VALUE"
    Object oMissing = System.Reflection.Missing.Value;
    //OBJECTS OF FALSE AND TRUE
    Object oTrue = true;
    Object oFalse = false;

    //CREATING OBJECTS OF WORD AND DOCUMENT
    Word.Application oWord = new Word.Application();
    Word.Document oWordDoc = new Word.Document();

    //THE LOCATION OF THE TEMPLATE FILE ON THE MACHINE
    string filePath = Path.Combine(HostingEnvironment.ApplicationPhysicalPath, @"App_Data\envelope3.dotx");
    Object oTemplatePath = filePath;

    //ADDING A NEW DOCUMENT FROM A TEMPLATE
    oWordDoc = oWord.Documents.Add(ref oTemplatePath, ref oMissing, ref oMissing, ref oMissing);
    for (int i = 0; i < dt.Rows.Count; i++)
    {
        string studentName = dt.Rows[i]["StudentName"].ToString();
        string studentID = dt.Rows[i]["StudentID"].ToString();
        string guard = dt.Rows[i]["GuardName"].ToString();
        string phone = dt.Rows[i]["Phone"].ToString();
        string address = dt.Rows[i]["Address"].ToString();
        string className = dt.Rows[i]["ClassName"].ToString();
        foreach (Word.Field myMergeField in oWordDoc.Fields)
        {
            int iTotalFields = 0;
            iTotalFields++;
            Word.Range rngFieldCode = myMergeField.Code;
            String fieldText = rngFieldCode.Text;

            // ONLY GETTING THE MAILMERGE FIELDS

            if (fieldText.StartsWith(" MERGEFIELD"))
            {

                // THE TEXT COMES IN THE FORMAT OF 

                // MERGEFIELD  MyFieldName  \\* MERGEFORMAT

                // THIS HAS TO BE EDITED TO GET ONLY THE FIELDNAME "MyFieldName"

                //Int32 endMerge = fieldText.IndexOf("\\");
                //Int32 fieldNameLength = fieldText.Length - endMerge;

                String fieldName = fieldText;//.Substring(11, endMerge - 11);
                // GIVES THE FIELDNAMES AS THE USER HAD ENTERED IN .dotx FILE

                fieldName = fieldName.Trim();
                // **** FIELD REPLACEMENT IMPLEMENTATION GOES HERE ****//
                // THE PROGRAMMER CAN HAVE HIS OWN IMPLEMENTATIONS HERE
                if (fieldName.Contains("SchoolName"))
                {
                    myMergeField.Select();
                    oWord.Selection.TypeText(schoolName);
                }
                else if (fieldName.Contains("SchoolAddr"))
                {
                    myMergeField.Select();
                    oWord.Selection.TypeText(schoolAddress);
                }
                else if (fieldName.Contains("StudentName"))
                {
                    myMergeField.Select();
                    oWord.Selection.TypeText(studentName);
                }
                else if (fieldName.Contains("StudentID"))
                {
                    myMergeField.Select();
                    oWord.Selection.TypeText(studentID);
                }
                else if (fieldName.Contains("GuardName"))
                {
                    myMergeField.Select();
                    oWord.Selection.TypeText(guard);
                }
                else if (fieldName.Contains("Phone"))
                {
                    myMergeField.Select();
                    oWord.Selection.TypeText(phone);
                }
                else if (fieldName.Contains("Address"))
                {
                    myMergeField.Select();
                    oWord.Selection.TypeText(address);
                }
                else if (fieldName.Contains("ClassName"))
                {
                    myMergeField.Select();
                    oWord.Selection.TypeText(className);
                }
            }
        }
        //Add to oWord to the final Word Document here
        Word.Selection sel = oWord.Selection;
        sel.InsertNewPage();
    }
    //SETTING THE VISIBILITY TO TRUE
    oWord.Visible = true;
}
```

What i did initially was, i was calling oWord.Visible = true on every iteration. It was opening a lot of word documents, though correct, it is not pleasant at all for me. I wish to put all those together into a single document by adding new pages to oWord. These new pages however do not contain the mergefields i need to replace.
Have searched around for it, but no results so far. I wish to continue use the Microsoft.Office.Interop

Comment: What you are doing is likely a bad idea. Use Office ActiveX Automation is not supported on a server, and you will encounter lots of problems. So even if you solve todays problem, you will have worse problems in the future. If you can execute the same automation via a winforms driver on your dev. workstation, it probably just means you are seeing the server problems already. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2653740/problems-with-office-automation-in-asp-net-i-can-use-alternatives-such-as-open for a short discussion of issues.

Comment: I did not notice your statement re: when making word visible it worked (maybe you added it). This virtually guarantees that your problem is due to the issues of using Interop on a server. You are beating your head against a rock for no good reason. If you docs are simple, you can probably relatively easily just write .rtf or .xml files compatible with Word via code, otherwise look at some of the available libraries. Some are free, some are big money. What you are doing will give cause hair loss.

Comment: ok, will try OpenXml format and see, whichever works, i will update this question with it. Which ones have you worked with and suggest we use?